# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080 from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, angular8, cross-origin-read-blocking

This is the method from my component:

```
onDelete(s) {
    const conf = confirm('etes vous sur');
    if (conf) {
         console.log(s._links.self.href);
      this.catservice.Deleteprod(s._links.self.href).subscribe(data => {console.log(s._links.self.href);
      }, error1 => {
        console.log(error1);
      });
    }
  }
```

and this the method from my service:

```
  public Deleteprod(url) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(url);
  }
```

I want to delete this object with `s._links.self.href` so the `url` is not wrong but I have this problem when I try to make class `websecurityconfig` with her methods I tried with `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` but there is no solution please help me.

This is my error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/offres/24' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image: this is my error i recupere the object but i cant delete it]

Comment: Please paste the `WebSecurityConfig` class, and also the controller class from where your service `Deleteprod` is being invoked. I believe `@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200"})` on top of the Controller class should work.

Comment: @CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200"}, allowedHeaders={"Accept"})
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{id}" )
    public void Delete(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id ) {
        offreRepositiory.deleteById(id);

    }

Answer (score 9):

Add the Following annotation below your `@RestController` Annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

in websecurity

```
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }


    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization");
    }
```

Comment: mapping is for `/api/` but you're calling `/offres/`?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by adding to the SecuityConfig the following code:

```
http.
   ..... //other code
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
   ..... //other code
```